# MySQL: Tablas para tipos de usuarios

Tags: mysql

Necesito implementar un login, pero tengo varios tipos de Usuarios, entonces para saber que tipo de usuarios son, debo de hacer 3 consultas (porque son 3 tipos de usuarios) ya que tengo una tabla Users a la cual las 3 tablas (Profesor, alumno y apoderado) estan relacionadas con un foreing key, mi pregunta es como puedo hacer para solo con el nombre se usuario saber que tipo de usuario es con una sola consulta, gracias

Answer (score 3):

Yo haría tres tablas:

1. Usuarios
2. Tipos
3. Usuarios_Tipos

La tercera tabla sería una tabla auxiliar en la que puedes poner en relación los usuarios con los tipos, de esta manera en una sola consulta podrías encontrar todos los usuarios, sus nombres, del tipo que son y más datos que necesites tanto de la tabla usuarios como de la tabla tipos (ver Query 1 más abajo).

Te dejo este diseño básico. Luego puedes crearle los índices, las claves primarias, controlar los registros que serán únicos, etc. Es sólo para mostrar cómo funcionaría.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/936b3/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE usuario
    (`usuario_id` int, `usuario_nom` varchar(70), `usuario_ape` varchar(70))
;


CREATE TABLE tipo
    (`tipo_id` int, `tipo_nom` varchar(70));


CREATE TABLE usuario_tipo
    (`usuario_id` int, `tipo_id` int);

INSERT INTO usuario (`usuario_id`, `usuario_nom`)
  VALUES
(1,"Pedro"),
(2,"Santiago"),
(3,"Juan"),
(4,"Andrés");



INSERT INTO tipo
    (`tipo_id`, `tipo_nom`)
VALUES
    (1, "Profesor"),
    (2, "Alumno"),
    (3, "Apoderado");

INSERT INTO usuario_tipo
    (`usuario_id`, `tipo_id`)
VALUES
    (1, 2),
    (3, 1),
    (2, 2),
    (4, 3);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT u.usuario_nom, t.tipo_nom
  FROM usuario u
  LEFT JOIN usuario_tipo ut 
      ON u.usuario_id = ut.usuario_id
  LEFT JOIN tipo t 
      ON t.tipo_id = ut.tipo_id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/936b3/1/0)**:

> ```
> | usuario_nom |  tipo_nom |
> |-------------|-----------|
> |        Juan |  Profesor |
> |       Pedro |    Alumno |
> |    Santiago |    Alumno |
> |      Andrés | Apoderado |
> ```

Comment: Apoyo tu respuesta, por el hecho de estar NORMALIZADA y eficiente, aunque yo lo haria solo con dos tablas, USUARIO y USUARIOS_TIPOS

Comment: @VictorA. Gracias. Eso depende del contexto. En un primer momento pensé en dos tablas solamente, pero... me decidí por tres tablas por un motivo: ¿y si un usuario puede ser a la vez Profesor y Apoderado? Esa simple novedad nos obligaría a cambiar la estructura de la BD... eso tendría su costo en una BD en producción, mientras que con la tabla auxiliar sólo tendríamos que escribir otra consulta agrupando o concatenando, si queremos ver los diferentes tipos de cada usuario...

Comment: entiendo @A.Cedano, tienes razon :) (Y)

Comment: Perfecto, gracias!

Comment: @A.Cedano Una consulta mas, si alguno de estos tipos de usuarios necesitan tener datos diferentes o relacionarse entre si? que podría hacer?

Comment: @JosephLeon Dame un ejemplo.

Comment: @A.Cedano tengo una tipo de usuario Alumno y otra de Apoderado, la tabla Alumno tiene que tener un clave foránea hacia la tabla Apoderado, en el caso de que implemente solo una tabla usuario, los usuarios que no sean alumnos tendrían ese campo siempre vacío y no se que tan bueno sea eso.

Comment: @JosephLeon No. Lo bueno de este diseño es que tendrías **una sola tabla con todos los usuarios** sin importar quienes sean y luego **otra tabla que serían los tipos**, todos los tipos juntos, no una tabla por cada tipo. Y en la tercera tabla, la **tabla auxiliar o asociativa** haces las relaciones poniendo en cada fila un usuario_id y un tipo_id eso te permite indicar que un usuario puede ser de varios tipos. En base de datos la idea es tener lo menos posible datos o tipos de datos que se repitan en varias tablas.

Answer (score 1):

Lo ideal sería que tu tabla de usuarios contuviera el tipo de usuario que es para lograr el efecto deseado, la respuesta que da  A. Cedano es ideal si es que tienes permitido cambiar tu modelo de la base de datos, pero asumiré sin mas informacion que lo quieres inferir apartar de la relación con las otras tablas, por lo que sería algo así sin conocer el esquema de tus tablas pero lo podrás adaptar de acuerdo a tu necesidad:

```
select *
from (
select 'PROFESOR' as TIPOUSUARIO, p.nombre, u.usuario from profesor as p join usuarios as u on p.id = u.id
union all
select 'ALUMNO' as TIPOUSUARIO, p.nombre, u.usuario from alumno as p join usuarios as u on p.id = u.id
union all
select 'APODERADO' as TIPOUSUARIO, p.nombre, u.usuario from apoderado as p join usuarios as u on p.id = u.id
  ) as unionTablas
 where usuario = 'a';
```

Enlace sqlfiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/40132/4/0

Comment: ¿Una tabla por cada tipo? ¿Y si hubiera la posibilidad de 50 tipos, o de 100 tipos, te imaginas, 50 tablas o 100 tablas? ¿Y si un usuario puede ser de varios tipos a la vez? ¿Y si luego surge un tipo nuevo? Las tablas son para agrupar datos comúnes, uno en cada línea. Con una sola tabla `Tipos` sería suficiente: en la línea 1 tendrías un tipo, en la línea 2 otro y así sucesivamente. Luego relacionas usuarios y tipos a través de una 3ª tabla auxiliar.

Comment: Por eso la sugerencia de recrear su modelo a algo mas practico como lo sugieres en tu respuesta, el OPespecifica en su pregunta como esta su modelo actual y no se sabe si es posible modificarlo en la instancia de desarrollo que esta o si es un sistema legado al cual estan modificando, fuera de ahi se busca contestar la pregunta del OP ya que este no pregunta por un modelo sino una respuesta a su modelo implementado actual saludos @A.Cedano

Comment: El hecho de que heredes un modelo mal concebido no significa que tengas que seguir manteniéndolo, mucho más si en un caso como éste sería muy fácil a través de consulta aislar en tablas separadas los datos que se repiten. Un diseño así se hace  inestable con el tiempo, difícil de mantener, lento, etc, etc. Y las "aparentes" soluciones que se busquen en realidad no lo son.

Comment: Concuerdo con lo que dices pero seguimos sin saber si el OP puede realizar cambios y este en posicion de hacerlos, autorizarlos o si su superior simplemente dijo sigue con ese modelo, lo cual lo puede meter en problemas al OP si arbitrariamente decide cambiarlo aunque este aporte un beneficio superior en muchos sentidos a largo plazo, repito el OP no pregunta por un mejor modelo, si no una respuesta a su modelo actual

Comment: Entendido. No había considerado ese caso, tienes razón en eso. Saludos.

Comment: No pasa nada estamos aqui para apoyarnos y dar opciones adicionales a los OP, y tu sugerencia es perfecta si es posible para el hacer el cambio y se lo hago mencion en mi respuesta, Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Yo crearía solo una tabla Usuarios con los campos necesarios, y un campo extra que seria tipoUser de tipo ENUM.

```
CREATE TABLE `Usuarios` ( `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `nombre` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , `tipoUser` ENUM('Profesor','Alumno','Apoderado') NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Entonces a la hora de realizar una consulta para recoger a todos los profesores solo tendrías que hacer la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM Usuarios WHERE tipoUser='Profesor';
```

Es lo más fácil y eficaz que hay. Así te libras de crear tablas innecesarias, que lo único que hacen es darte más trabajo a la hora de realizar una consulta, por que tienes que ir relacionando las Foreign Keys, etc.

Creo que mi respuesta solo te será útil si solo van a existir esos tres tipos de usuarios y no van a existir más.

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias amigo