# Problema para modelar una relacion 1-N

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Mas que una pregunta, surge un debate al momento de modelar la base de datos de un software para gestión de salud ocupacional. La pregunta es la siguiente, tenemos dos entidades, una entidad `Persona` y la otra llamada `EPS` y al hacer la relación entre las dos nos surge el debate si el `Id` de una debería estar en la otra y viceversa. Explico:

Una persona DEBE estar en una sola `EPS`, no puede estar en varias; una `EPS` tiene muchas `Personas` vinculadas. Por concepto de cardinalidad se dice que en una relación de uno a muchos, el muchos debe tener el `Id` del uno, en otras palabras una `Persona` debe tener la llave foránea de `Id`. Pero debatiendo algunos dicen que en la entidad `EPS` debe tener el `Id` de la `Persona`. ¿Cuál sería la manera correcta de modelar este problema?

Comment: ¿Cuál es el argumento para colocar el ID de la persona como foránea en EPS?

Comment: @RenzoMaldonado El argumento que toman es que no es necesrio tener ese campo en Persona ya que es un campo como que puede o no tener.

Comment: Te diré que _ni una ni otra_ Yo crearía una **tercera tabla asociativa** en la que pondría los id de usuarios y los id de EPS que estuviesen relacionados. Mira este ejemplo, que te puede ilustrar mejor lo que quiero decir: http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/55667/29967 No tiene sentido poner los ids de usuarios en la tabla EPS (sería una locura), ni tampoco hacer lo contrario (sería otra locura). Desde que haya una relación uno a varios de cualquier lado, piensa de inmediato en una tercera tabla que maneje las relaciones entre ambas.

Comment: @A.Cedano gracias por tu comentario, pero refuto en cierto aspecto tu argumento ya que como decia la persona solo puede tener UNA EPS, por lo tanto no es una relacion Muchos a Muchos y no sale tabla resultante

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con la Tabla asociativa. Eso haría que el modelado fuera mejor ya que la entidad EPS podría llegar a ser muy ancha. Por otro lado por lo que entiendo la entidad EPS si debe tener el ID de la persona. Seria la forma adecuada de relacionarse desde el N al 1

Comment: *Pero debatiendo algunos dicen que en la entidad EPS debe tener el ID de la persona*. Si es cierto que una EPS puede estar asociado a varias personas, mas allá de si es corecto o no, no veo siquiera como es posible tener el ID de la persona en la entidad EPS. Hay algo que no entiendo.

Comment: @JuanCarlosPeñaM. El que sólo pueda tener una EPS no impide que implementes un modelo asociativo. Yo no haría nunca que una tabla sea esclava de otra colocando una clave foránea de otra tabla, a no ser que sea estrictamente necesario. Planteo dos cuestiones interesantes: 1. **¿En la tabla EPS tengo muchas filas repetidas, menos en la columna id_persona y en la clave primaria**? Si es sí **debo tener una tabla asociativa**. 2. **¿Es posible que algún día pueda haber una relación Varios a Varios entre las 2 tablas?** Si es sí, **debo tener una tabla asociativa**.

Comment: El ID de EPS se podría colocar como foránea en la Persona por simplicidad. Sin embargo, te recomendaría la tercera tabla asociativa que menciono @A.Cedano con una validación que solo te permita insertar una EPS por Persona. De esta forma si ocurren cambios en las reglas de negocio a futuro, el impacto de los cambios a realizar seria mínimo.

Comment: Y plantearía además una 3ª pregunta que podría ayudar a decidir sobre el modelo a implementar: 3. **¿Qué es lo que impide tener todas las columnas de EPS en la tabla persona?**

Comment: Tiene logica los que ambos debates, espero mas puntos de vista al respecto del tema, si todos concuerdan puedo dar el tema finalizado con esa respuesta. Muchas gracias

Comment: La tabla de personas debiese tener el id de su EPS. Es la opción más simple. La idea de una tabla relación es más mantenible y flexible. Puedes resguardar la integridad referencial estableciendo que la combinación de idpersona y ideps es una llave única, que borrar una eps borra las relaciones, y borrar una relación deja el eps de la persona en null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tomando como ejemplo las siguientes entidades y algunos de sus datos:

Entidad **EPS**:

```
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| EPSId | Campo1    | Campo2    | Campo3    |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 1     | C1 - EPS1 | C2 - EPS1 | C3 - EPS1 |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 2     | C1 - EPS2 | C2 - EPS2 | C3 - EPS2 |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 3     | C1 - EPS3 | C2 - EPS3 | C3 - EPS3 |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Entidad **Persona**:

```
+-----------+---------+---------+---------+
| PersonaId | Campo1  | Campo2  | Campo3  |
+-----------+---------+---------+---------+
| 1         | C1 - P1 | C2 - P1 | C3 - P1 |
+-----------+---------+---------+---------+
| 2         | C1 - P2 | C2 - P2 | C3 - P2 |
+-----------+---------+---------+---------+
| 3         | C1 - P3 | C2 - P3 | C3 - P3 |
+-----------+---------+---------+---------+
| 4         | C1 - P4 | C2 - P4 | C3 - P4 |
+-----------+---------+---------+---------+
| 5         | C1 - P5 | C2 - P5 | C3 - P5 |
+-----------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Sabiendo que una `Persona` debe estar relacionado a un solo `EPS` pero un `EPS` puede tener más de una `Persona`, expongo principalmente 3 casos:

## Caso 1: La entidad `Persona` debe tener la llave foránea del `EPSId`

Finalmente, la tabla `Persona` solo se tendría que agregar la referencia foránea de la tabla `EPS` quedando algo así:

```
+-----------+---------+---------+---------+-------+
| PersonaId | Campo1  | Campo2  | Campo3  | EPSId |
+-----------+---------+---------+---------+-------+
| 1         | C1 - P1 | C2 - P1 | C3 - P1 | 1     |
+-----------+---------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2         | C1 - P2 | C2 - P2 | C3 - P2 | 1     |
+-----------+---------+---------+---------+-------+
| 3         | C1 - P3 | C2 - P3 | C3 - P3 | 2     |
+-----------+---------+---------+---------+-------+
| 4         | C1 - P4 | C2 - P4 | C3 - P4 | 3     |
+-----------+---------+---------+---------+-------+
| 5         | C1 - P5 | C2 - P5 | C3 - P5 | 3     |
+-----------+---------+---------+---------+-------+
```

*(5 registros en la tabla `Persona` y 3 registros en la tabla `EPS`)*

## Caso 2: La entidad `EPS` debe tener la llave foránea de `PersonaId`

Este es un caso más complicado, ya que tendrás información duplicada y se tendría que agregar `PersonaId` como parte de la llave para que al final se genere una llave compuesta por `EPS` y `PersonaId`, quedando algo así:

```
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| EPSId | Campo1    | Campo2    | Campo3    | PersonaId |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 1     | C1 - EPS1 | C2 - EPS1 | C3 - EPS1 | 1         |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 1     | C1 - EPS1 | C2 - EPS1 | C3 - EPS1 | 2         |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 2     | C1 - EPS2 | C2 - EPS2 | C3 - EPS2 | 3         |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 3     | C1 - EPS3 | C2 - EPS3 | C3 - EPS3 | 4         |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 3     | C1 - EPS3 | C2 - EPS3 | C3 - EPS3 | 5         |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Como podrás ver, los `EPSId` se repiten, y suponiendo que tienes grandes cantidades de información se pueden complicar las búsquedas.

*(5 registros en la tabla `Persona` y 5 registros en la tabla `EPS`)*

## Caso 3: Una tabla intermedia con la referencia de `PersonaId` y `EPSId`

Este caso sería funcional en caso de que desees una relación de muchos a muchos, esto evitaría tener información *duplicada* en una o en otra tabla. No considero que sea una mala práctica ya que finalmente se mantiene normalizada la información, quedando las entidades como las mostraba en un inicio y creando otra tabla quedando algo así:

```
+-------+-----------+
| EPSId | PersonaId |
+-------+-----------+
| 1     | 1         |
+-------+-----------+
| 1     | 2         |
+-------+-----------+
| 2     | 3         |
+-------+-----------+
| 3     | 4         |
+-------+-----------+
| 3     | 5         |
+-------+-----------+
```

Que para este ejemplo, sería algo similar al Caso 2.

*(5 registros en la tabla `Persona`, 3 registros en la tabla `EPS` y 3 registros en la tabla intermedia `PersonaEPS`)*

Como bien lo mencionas en tu pregunta, "*Por concepto de cardinalidad se dice que en una relación de uno a muchos, el muchos debe tener el `Id` del uno, en otras palabras una `Persona` debe tener la llave foránea de `Id`*", entonces, **el caso 1 debería ser el ideal para este escenario.**

Comment: Creo que mejor respuesta no se encuentra. Muchas gracias! Pues el caso 1 es lo correcto, pero el 3 tampoco seria una mala pratica. Ahora en decision unanime con mi grupo lo debatire y tomeremos alguno de los dos casos

Comment: @JuanCarlosPeñaM. es correcto, también sería una opción, siempre y cuando en algún momento del futuro se planee o se prevea un cambio de estructura de muchos a muchos :)

Answer (score 2):

**Depende.**

Vamos a analizar de primero por qué el enfoque del `id` de la entidad `persona` en la entidad `EPS` es incorrecto. Luego analizaremos las ventajas y desventajas de utilizar el `id` de `EPS` en la entidad `persona`, y el utilizar una tabla intermedia.

> **Enfoque id de persona en EPS**

Supongamos que nuestra entidad `EPS` es como muestra el diagrama, con llave primaria compuesta por `id_eps` y `id_persona`:

```
|------------------------------------------------------------|
| id_eps   |    nombre          | descripcion   | id_persona |
|----------|--------------------|---------------|------------|
|    1     |  Seguro Bienestar  |   ninguna     |     1      |
|    1     |  Seguro Bienestar  |   ninguna     |     2      |
|    2     |  EPS El Mejor      |   es el mejor |     3      |
|    1     |  Seguro Bienestar  |   ninguna     |     4      |
|    2     |  EPS El Mejor      |   es el mejor |     5      |
|    3     |  Viva la Salud     |   ninguna     |     6      |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

La entidad se encuentra en primera forma normal (1FN). Sin embargo, a simple vista podemos observar que algo anda mal: la redundancia de datos, lo que nos lleva a una serie de problemas al tratar de trabajar con ella (**anomalías de actualización**):

- **Insert**: ¿Qué sucede si queremos agregar un nuevo EPS (que aún no
  tiene afiliados)? No podríamos, dado que `id_persona` sería nulo, y el
  campo no puede ser nulo porque es parte de la llave primaria.
- **Update**: ¿Qué sucede si queremos modificar el nombre del EPS con `id_eps`
  1? Tendríamos que buscar todos los registros correspondientes y
  cambiar el nombre, o exponernos a una inconsistencia de datos si
  olvidamos incluir uno.
- **Delete**: Imaginemos que deseamos eliminar al cliente con `id_persona`
  6, y este es el único afiliado que posee el EPS con `id_eps` 3.
  Estaríamos eliminando no solo el cliente, sino también el único
  registro que tenemos de ese EPS.

Estos problemas que nos provoca la tabla por estar únicamente en 1FN, se dan cuando intentamos manejar `id_persona` en ella. Como vemos, no solo es el hecho de estar almacenando información repetida, sino que es imposible trabajar con ella si queremos mantener la base de datos consistente. En este punto, **no existe el debate**. Simplemente, no es ninguna alternativa.

¿Qué solución le podemos dar? Bueno, seguir normalizando. Separamos los atributos que no son dependientes de la llave primaria en una nueva entidad. Así que nuestra tabla EPS sería la siguiente, con llave primaria `id_eps` (está tabla se encuentra en 3FN):

```
|-----------------------------------------------|
| id_eps   |    nombre          | descripcion   |
|----------|--------------------|---------------|
|    1     |  Seguro Bienestar  |   ninguna     |
|    2     |  EPS El Mejor      |   es el mejor |
|    3     |  Viva la Salud     |   ninguna     |
-------------------------------------------------
```

Ahora si, al debate.

> **Enfoque id de EPS en persona**

Esto significa que nuestra entidad `persona` es mas o menos así, con llave primaria `id_persona` y una llave foránea `id_eps`:

```
|----------------------------------------------------------------|
| id_persona   |    nombre          | apellido      | id_ eps    |
|--------------|--------------------|---------------|------------|
|    1         |  Juan Carlos       |   López Deras |     1      |
|    2         |  Silvia Abigail    |   Rodríguez   |     2      |
|    3         |  Pedro José        |   Silva Peréz |     3      |
|    4         |  Karla Alejandra   |   Gomez       |     1      |
|    5         |  Rebeca María      |   Alvarado    |     2      |
|    6         |  Pablo Silvio      |   Ortega      |     2      |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

La tabla está en 3FN. Yo diría que existen diversos criterios a analizar, pero me voy a enfocar en tres: rendimiento, veracidad de la información y escalabilidad.

En cuánto al rendimiento, al tener como llave foránea id_eps, permite que las consultas sobre EPS y sus clientes solo manejen un JOIN entre dos tablas.

En cuánto a la veracidad de la información, no es posible ingresar más de una vez un cliente para dos o mas EPS. Cada cliente pertenece a un único EPS, de lo contrario intentaría violar la integridad de la llave primaria.

El problema podría estar en la escalabilidad: ¿Qué sucede si se implementa el modelo, todos felices y contentos, y un día nos solicitan que se maneje información sobre las fechas de vinculación/desvinculación con los EPS? Así mismo, el usuario que realizó el registro y la fecha de la transacción.

Podríanos afrontarlo de la siguiente manera (los campos son continuación de la tabla de `persona`, pero los separé por cuestiones de formato):

```
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------|
| id_persona   | fecha vinculación  | fecha desvinculación | usuario    |
|--------------|--------------------|----------------------|------------|
|    1         |  21/02/2014        |   null               |    jlan    |
|    2         |  15/03/2014        |   null               |    neo     |
|    3         |  01/04/2015        |   null               |    admin   |
|    4         |  28/04/2015        |   null               |    ddam    |
|    5         |  31/12/2015        |   null               |     su     |
|    6         |  02/07/2017        |   null               |     sa     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Cumplimos con lo solicitado, pero podemos comenzar a ver que estos datos ya no tienen tanto que ver con la entidad `persona` como tal. Podemos crear una tabla nueva para esto, con la llave primaria compuesta de `id_eps` y `id_persona` , pero podríamos haber visto esto desde el principio con el siguiente enfoque:

> **Tabla intermedia entre EPS y persona**

Aunque la cardinalidad nos invita al enfoque anterior, vimos que si la base de datos escala, podríamos habernos evitado algunos problemas si en lugar de pensar en cardinalidad, hubieramos pensado en la relación que se da entre las tablas.

¿Que hay entre un EPS y una persona que los vincula? Podría ser un `contrato` con llave primaria compuesta de `id_persona` y `id_eps`:

```
|---------------------------------------------------------------------|
| id_persona   | id_eps  | fecha vinculación   | fecha desvinculación |
|--------------|---------|---------------------|----------------------|
|    1         |    1    |   21/02/2014        |   null               |
|    2         |    1    |   15/03/2014        |   null               |
|    3         |    2    |   01/04/2015        |   null               |
|    4         |    1    |   28/04/2015        |   null               |
|    5         |    2    |   31/12/2015        |   null               |
|    6         |    3    |   02/07/2017        |   null               |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

La tabla está en 3FN, y ahora si tienen más sentido los campos fechas de vinculación y fecha de desvinculación en un `contrato` que en una `persona`. Además, podríamos agregar fácilmente campos de motivo de desvinculación, usuario que registra, fecha de registro, etc; sin alterar la información que ya tenemos de nuestros EPS y personas.

Pero no todo es perfecto. En este ejemplo, una consulta que involucre los nombres de los EPS y los nombres de sus clientes equivale a un JOIN entre tres tablas. Para el ejemplo, es sencillo, pero normalmente las bases de datos tienen decenas de tablas y si normalizamos demasiado (pasarnos de la 3FN, por ejemplo), una consulta tan sencilla fácilmente puede involucrar  un JOIN entre cinco, seis o más tablas, haciendo que la información sea costosa de obtener.

*"Ha, pero yo creé índices y el query plan me indica que los utiliza, así que no hay problema con múltiples joins"*. Excelente, pero **un índice añade un costo en las operaciones de insert y update**. Si el sistema es muy transaccional, esto podría significar una baja en el rendimiento. No digamos si manejamos mas de tres o cuatro indices por tabla, y si al escalar, modificamos las tablas y hay que recalcular todas las estadísticas. A veces se vuelve prohíbitivo. Aquí en SO he visto preguntas sobre consultas que tardan horas en ejecutarse, y aunque muchas de las consultas se realizan mal, en algunas se puede observar un diseño que no estaba pensado para un volumen alto de datos.

Adicional a esto, supongamos que por descuido o error (o intencionalmente) se ingresa un cliente que ya existía, con un nuevo EPS en la tabla `contrato`:

```
|---------------------------------------------------------------------|
| id_persona   | id_eps  | fecha vinculación   | fecha desvinculación |
|--------------|---------|---------------------|----------------------|
|    1         |    1    |   21/02/2014        |   null               |
|    1         |    3    |   03/07/2017        |   null               |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

El segundo registro es el problema. La base de datos se mantiene integra y consistente, pero su información ya no es veraz. A diferencia del enfoque anterior, aquí no se rompe la integridad de la llave primaria, por lo que es necesario tomar una medida previa al realizar un insert en esta tabla: una búsqueda previa, por ejemplo, y esto agrega un costo al proceso de crear un nuevo contrato.

En resumen, el saber que enfoque tomar te lo dará (en mi opinión) la experiencia (principalmente la laboral). Si la tarea o ejercicio trata de cardinalidad, toma el primer enfoque, pero en el mundo real el diseño y modelado va mucho más allá de la cardinalidad:

¿La base de datos es relacional?
¿Es un OLTP o un OLAP? Si es un OLTP, ¿que nivel de transaccionalidad tendrá?
¿Qué volumen de datos manejan las tablas?
¿Existen medidas de seguridad previas en el envío de información a la base de datos?
¿Qué tan factible es que pidan modificaciones posteriores?