# ¿Cómo hacer una consulta en dos tablas en un solo formulario?

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

Buenas noches comunidad.
Estoy desarrollando una plataforma web donde se pueden registrar dos tipos de usuarios, digamoslo así:"UsuarioA" y "UsuarioB"(cada usuario tiene distintos datos y están en tablas diferentes).
Hice un login en el que no importa que tipo de usuario sea, con ingresar su correo registrado le de acceso ya que le hice un perfil distinto a cada uno.

Hasta ahora solo tengo el login establecido para el UsuarioA, este es mi código:

```
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        if (DB::query('SELECT email FROM usuarioA WHERE email=:email', array(':email'=>$email))) {
                if (password_verify($password, DB::query('SELECT password FROM registroalumnos WHERE email=:email', array(':email'=>$email))[0]['password'])) {
                        echo 'Logged in!';
```

Tengo otra tabla en la misma BD que se llama usuarioB y pido lo mismo, email y password... cómo podría hacer que llame ambas?.

Gracias.

Comment: Poder se puede hacer, pero ese es un error de diseño claramente, no hay necesidad de crear 2 tablas, por lo que mi recomendacion es que unifiques en una sola tabla y añadas un campo para indicar el rol del usuario.

Comment: Estoy contigo @Xerif, esto se podría hacer mediante tablas relacionadas. Antonio, [aquí tienes un ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/55667/29967) en el que se gestionan tipos o roles de usuarios. En este caso, el tipo de usuario sería manejado en otra tabla, mientras que los datos de todos los usuarios (que serían en teoría los mismos independiente del tipo) estarían en una sola tabla.

Comment: Posiblemente existen muchas mas soluciones, pero lo primero, y lo más simple que se me ocurre sería, hacer un `SELECT COUNT(email) FROM registroalumnos`, en caso de devolver un número mayor a 0, procedes al login en A, sino, misma query en B, de todos modos, a simple vista se puede notar que has tenido un problema a nivel diseño de base de datos, es altamente recomendable un rediseño, y realizar el proceso de normalización. Saludos!